# Show there's no linear relation between X and Y

Tags: probability, self-study

$\newcommand{\Cov}{\mathrm{Cov}}$
$\newcommand{\E}{\mathrm{E}}$

Show that if the joint of $X$ and $Y$, $f(x, y) = \frac{1}{2}\sin(x + y)$ for $0 \leq x, y \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $0$ everywhere else, then there is no linear relation between $X$ and $Y$.

My strategy is to show that $\Cov(X, Y) = 0$, so I work out the marginal distributions.

$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{2}[\sin(x) + \cos(x)]$

$\E(X) = \frac{\pi}{4}$ using integration by parts.

But then I get to $\Cov(X, Y) = \E(XY) - \frac{\pi^2}{16}$ using the linearity of expectation, but $\E(XY) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{2}xy\sin(x + y) \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y = \frac{\pi}{2} - 1 \neq \frac{\pi^2}{16}$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The correct covariance is indeed $-(\pi-4)^2/16\approx -0.0460539.$

Comment: Your calculations seems correct, maybe Y and X has a linear relation

Comment: Since the wording of the question is vague, an answer is that $Y$ is not a deterministic linear transform of $X$ (and vice-versa).

Comment: A quick simulation suggests the relationship between E(Y|X=x) and x appears consistent with it being conditionally linear (and, by symmetry, vice-versa); there was no hint of nonlinearity in the conditional means of the residuals. I didn't go on to do the algebra to check it though.

Comment: If linear relation means that $|\rho| = 1$, then I suppose there's no linear relation for this question.